# How can I monitor the memory usage of a shell script at runtime?

Tags: shell, memory, monitoring

I haz shell script like this:

```
while true;do
    curl -s example.com | egrep -o 'sth'
    sleep 60
done
```

How can I get the total memory usage of process `bash` and `curl` and `egrep` and `sleep` at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ps command:

```
 ps aux | grep <scriptName>
 ps aux | grep "curl -s example"
 ps aux | grep "egrap -s 'sth'"
 ps aux | grep "sleep 60"
```

the 3rd and 4th columns are cpu and mem (you can get them using awk)

Comment: You could also combine all those four lines into a single one using grep's -e option: `ps axu | grep -e <scriptname> -e "curl -s example" -e "egrep -s 'sth'" -e "sleep 60" | cut -f3,4`. Even if you want the code to span multiple lines (e.g. for cosmetic reasons) you can still do this by ending all but the final line with backslash (`\`) but then you start only one instance of grep instead of four.